# Why I can't use debugger or console.log on my Vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I just created a new Vue app through Vue CLI but **I can't use either debugger or console.log** otherwise I get an error in the browser, **why and how can I allow it** ?

```
Unexpected 'debugger' statement (no-debugger) at src/components/SomeComponent.vue:48:7
```

Comment: It would really help if you added the error you're getting  and when you get that error... Is it a linting error? Is it a Webpack error? I know that you've already answered your own question but giving other context would still be helpful.

Comment: Edited with the error I was getting, and yeah it was a linting error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case it was because I went with the default configs when creating my project and it includes eslint:

[image: my project's plugins]

So in order to allow debugger and console.log statements I modified the rules on my package.json file like this:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-console": 1,
        "no-debugger": 1
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  }
```

This way I still get a warning when compiling so I don't forget to remove them before committing but I can run my app and use those statements.

Comment: Typically es list is set to warn not stop on those errors so you're app should have still run... Also in my experience you can fix most of those by being more specific about how you call the console eg `window.console.log()` vs `console.log()`

Comment: Hmm weird, the eslint config is the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
//eslint-disable-next-line no-console
```

only if your really have to use `console.log()`

otherwise I **highly recommend** to use a logger like '`vuejs-logger`'.

What happens is like in production you still have these console.log lines that I actually don't like a lot... plus the warning during rebuilding prevents you from using the hot reload of your app during development.

Comment: I see, yeah but these console.log statements are only for debugging / dev. Those would be removed before commiting the code.

Comment: What I do is I use `husky` to run the linter before git commit / push.